# res.json is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I have a file with the following function. This function returns JSON. I want to call this function from another file.

```
  exports.me = function(req, res) {
  var userId = req.user._id;
  User.findOne({
    _id: userId
  }, function(err, user) { 
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!user) return res.json(401);
    res.json(user);
  });
};
```

I'm doing following but i get res.json is not a function, I dont know how to receive a json to a variable. Also looks like an async problem. Please help.

```
var user = require('user');
var loggedIn = user.me(req, function(user){

  return user;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `me()` function appear to be an express request event handler. Therefore the res variable is expected to be a [response](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) object. In your code you are passing a function as second argument and thats the reason of the error.

Additionally the `me()` function doesn't have a return value and therefore the value of the `loggedIn` variable will be undefined.